# Use javascript to auto click a picture when user moves mouse pointer over the picture

Tags: javascript, mouseover

my idea is a script that auto click the picture when user moves mouse pointer over the picture. Please guide me how to make it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What's the point ? What if I accidentally hover on that pic ?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I support such a thing. but...

```
el = document.getElementById('lol');
el.onmouseover = function(){el.click();}

el.onclick = function(){
    //your code for having clicked the element
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rap6M/

But!, why not just put your code in the `onmouseover` listener? Especially seeing that (though widely acceptable) not all browsers suppoer the `el.click()`

Here is what MDN has to say about click(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click

Noting that they say:

> However, bubbling of a click event will not cause an `<a>` element to
>   initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to trigger a DOM [mouse onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event but during mouse overs on certain elements (in this case a picture).

My suggestion would be to just trigger the event (mouse onclick) whenever you hover over the image. Just have an event listener on your object listening for a [onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) event, once you detect it, fire off a click event on whatever element you need to.

Take a look at this:

```
<img id="my_image" src="myimage.png"></img>
<div id="my_clicky_div">My click event will be triggered</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_clicky_div").on("click", function() {
        console.log("My click event has been triggered!")
    })
    $("#my_image").on("mouseover", function() {
        $("#my_clicky_div").trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

You create an image tag and a div. Whenever you hover (mouseover) this image, the div's onclick event is triggered.

To make it easier, you should just bind whatever event you need triggered onto the onmouseover event, you essentially bypass a step as so:

```
<img id="my_image" src="myimage.png"></img>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_image").on("mouseover", function() {
    // Instead of issuing another event, run the code that happens during the click event 
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps!

References:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/, http://api.jquery.com/trigger/, http://api.jquery.com/on